# Expected Identifier, String or number edit line 298

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers, identifier

i need help on this IE8 issue. I couldn't find what went wrong, everything looks fine but still error in IE8. Works fine in chrome and FF.

```
if($("#tContent_data table").length > 0){
                    var table = $("#tContent_data table");
                    var parentTd = $("#tContent_data table").parent();

                            $("#tContent_data p").css("width","738px");
                            if($("#tContent_data table").attr('width')){
                            }else{
                                var stylewidth = $("#tContent_data table").css("width");
                                var swidth = stylewidth.substring(0,stylewidth.length - 2);

                                if (parseInt(swidth) > 738){
                                    $("#tContent_data table").css("width","1000px");
                                }
                                $("#tContent_data table").attr('width','100%');
                                var tr = $("#tContent_data table tr");
                                for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
                                    var tds = ("#tContent_data table tr td");
                                    var tdwidth = 100/tds.length;

                                    for(var x = 0; x < tds.length; x++){

                                        $("#tContent_data table tbody tr td").eq(x).css("width",""+tdwidth+"%");
                                        if ($("#tContent_data table tbody tr td p").length){
                                            var pwidth = tdwidth/$("#tContent_data table tbody tr td p").length;
                                            $("#tContent_data table tbody tr td p").css("width","100%");

                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                    }
```

Comment: But which one is the line 298?

Comment: Is the 298th line even contained in this snippset ?

Comment: line 298 points to $("#tContent_data table").css("width","1000px");